# Looking for best way to show random youtube videos on my site with 10 or less views

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Looking for best way to show random youtube videos on my site with 10 or less views. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to Jeff Posnick from YouTube API Team:

> I can't say that I have enough of a background in statistics to 
>   suggest how you could retrieve a truly random sample of videos. I do 
>   think that going about it by attempting to generate 11 character 
>   YouTube video ids is probably the wrong approach, though—there are 
>   just too many non-existent video ids that you'll bump up against, and 
>   I don't think the best use of the API is to make requests that will 
>   return HTTP 404 responses X% of the time.
>
> You might have better luck just using the API to search for words or 
>   phrases that are picked at "random" and taking a sampling of the 
>   results.

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/M3UYFxf5SD0

You could then use view count for the orderby= URL parameter. The default ordering is "relevance", which will lead to the top results being the ones that YouTube algorithms think are the most relevant to your search terms.

```
GET {base_URL}/search?part=snippet
                     &forMine=true
                     &order=viewCount
                     &type=video
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests

Comment: Do you know how I could show say random youtube videos by date uploaded that way they will be new videos. ?

Comment: The JSON structure of a videos resource includes publishedAt. The date and time that the video was published. Note that this time might be different than the time that the video was uploaded. For example, if a video is uploaded as a private video and then made public at a later time, this property will specify the time that the video was made public. The value is specified in ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format. Ref: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos